# Why does java have both the cacerts and jssecacerts files?

Tags: java, ssl, jsse, truststore

I'm seriously confused on the differences between `cacerts` and `jssecacerts` files.

I know that by default java looks for the `jssecacerts` file and then the `cacerts` file.

But what is the point of the `jssecacerts` file?

My understanding is that if a new truststore needs to be used then a copy of `cacerts` should be made and all new trusted CAs should be added to that copy. The copy of `cacerts` (with the new CAs) should then be referenced by the `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` system property.  That way other java applications that run on that machine won't accidently trust non-default CAs.

Comment: do you really find none of the 3 answers to be the correct one?  Could you select the one you deem to be correct please?

Answer (score 46):

From [Java™ Secure Socket Extension (JSSE) Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#X509TrustManager), `TrustManagerFactory` uses the following steps to try to find trust material:

1. system property `javax.net.ssl.trustStore`
2. `java-home/lib/security/jssecacerts`
3. `java-home/lib/security/cacerts` (shipped by default)

I think this is based on convention over configuration concept. Without extra coding effort, `cacert` will be used. For extra private CA/Signing certs, a developer either can use first or second way, where former may just contain a particular cert but later contains a list of certs.

Comment: The point being once it finds 1, 2, or 3 it uses that exclusively, so jssecacerts would need to include ALL the certs if used.

Answer (score 25):

As I understand it, the `cacerts` file is the shipped default one.

If there is a `jssecacerts` file it is used exclusively - not in addition to the `cacerts` file.

My recommendation: keep the `cacerts` file, copy to `jssecacerts` and add any private CA/Signing certs needed to the `jssecacerts` file.

Comment: Thanks for this, I too found that having a CA in cacerts doesn't work if a jssecacerts file exists, and it needs to be added to jssecacerts instead.

Comment: @EJP You are not "clobber"ing the shipped jssecacerts file.  There is no jssecacerts file shipped.  By copying cacerts to jssecacerts Java will now use jssecacerts instead.  Now you can add/remote certs from jssecacerts using `keytool` without worrying about changing the defaults (cacerts) that shipped with Java.  Undoing any changes is as easy as removing jssecacerts from the directory.

Answer (score 4):

Good question. I think it arises from the historical fact that JSSE was once an add-on. JSSE does allow multiple providers, so maybe `jssecacerts` is only for the JSSE provider, and other providers might use their own.

But who used cacerts prior to JSSE is another question.